# Large matrix inversion in R error after 250x250

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

I receive the following error when trying to perform matrix inversion on a matrix that is larger than 250x250. I only receive the error if the size of the matrix exceeds this size.

```
Error in solve.default(S) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.10729e-20
```

I've tried other matrices larger than this that do invert. I've checked for multicollinearity in the matrix and there is none. What could cause this error?

Edit: changing the tolerance does prevent the error. But why does the error get thrown only when the matrix is larger than 250x250?

Comment: Have you tried altering your value for `tol`?

Comment: I have. That does prevent the error, but it doesn't explain why the error seems to be generated at only 250 or greater. @Lyngbakr

Comment: You may have attempted to "check for multicollinearity" (although you describe no methods) but the error message is telling you that whatever methods you chose were inadequate at least up to numerical accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with calculating matrices of size greater than 250:

```
set.seed(12345)
N = 300
m <- matrix(rnorm(N*N), nrow = N)
str(m)
# num [1:300, 1:300] 0.586 0.709 -0.109 -0.453 0.606 ...

m.inv <- solve(m)
str(m.inv)
# num [1:300, 1:300] 0.0274 -0.0164 0.0384 -0.0936 -0.1086 ...
```

However if the determinant of matrix is 0 (or almost zero), then obviously there will be an error calculating an inverse:

```
p <- matrix(7, nrow = N, ncol=N)
str(p)
# num [1:300, 1:300] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...

p.inv <- solve(p)
#Error in solve.default(p) : 
#  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0
```

In your case it looks like you are operating with very small values. Try to specify a smaller tolerance:

```
solve(..., tol = 1e-17)

# You can check the current tollerance on your system:
.Machine$double.eps
#[1] 2.220446e-16
```

A better approach is probably to calculate determinant first and then handle the cases where it is very small:

```
det(p)
#[1] 0
```

To answer your question why the error occurs only when your matrix is larger than 250 elements, I would recommend that you calculate the determinant for your 250x250 matrix and then compute the determinant for a larger matrix and compare the values. The second value is probably smaller than the tolerance, while the first one is not.

Comment: I think you meant determinant instead of discriminant

Comment: @percusse Fixed. This was a typo. Thank you.